# No hay suficiente información para inferir el parámetro T

Tags: java, kotlin

Estoy intentando realizar una app con Kotlin pero me genera error al momento de utilizar `findViewByID`en la siguiente clase:

```
class AprendiendoKotlin : Activity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_aprendiendo_kotlin)
        val txt = findViewById(R.id.mensaje) as TextView
        txt.setText("Si funciona")
    }
}
```

El error lo genera en `findViewByID` que dice:

> Type inferenced failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T in fun `<T:View!> findViewById(id:Int): T`! Please specify it explicitly.

Es la actividad principal. ¿Por qué ocurre esto y cómo puedo solucionar el problema?

Comment: Hola Santiago Amado, he editado la publicación para añadir la ifnormación que ponías en el comentario directamente en el cuerpo de la pregunta. Cuando tengas un segundo, completa el [tour] para aprender más sobre el sitio (y así ganar tu primera medalla).

Comment: Gracias Alvaro.

Comment: Creo que [aquí](http://flipandroid.com/no-es-capaz-de-findviewbyid-en-kotlin-error-de-obtencin-inferencia-de-tipo-no.html) puedes encontrar la solución

Answer (score 1):

La asignatura del metodo `findViewById` fue modificada a `findViewById<T>()` por lo que tienes que especificarle el tipo de la vista a buscar:

```
class AprendiendoKotlin : Activity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        //...
        val txt = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.mensaje)
        //..
```

Esto solo desde el API 26.